# Why do node tasks spawn new console when run from PowerShell?

Tags: node.js, windows, powershell

On Windows 10, when I run Node.js commands (e.g. `node -v`) from a PowerShell console, they always spawn a new Windows Command console. When I run the same commands from a Windows Command prompt, they run in that same console session. Interestingly, whatever this is appears to cause the same behavior when running Node commands via the Task runner in Visual Studio Code and when Visual Studio 2017 build steps contain Node commands - each Node command run spawns a new console. This only started about a week or so ago. I don't recall any updates to my PC that could be related. Other developers on my team that use the same tools don't experience this same behavior. I have another PC that this doesn't occur on. What could be causing this?

Windows 10

Node.js v7.8

[image: Node.js command in PowerShell spawns Windows Command]

Comment: Show output of `Get-Command node -All` in PowerShell. And output of `where node` in CMD.

Comment: @PetSerAl : From PS: `Application node.exe 7.8.0.0  C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe`. From cmd: `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe`

Comment: Any other program have the same issue? For example, if you run `cmd` from PowerShell, will it run in the same window? And what if you start `cmd /c node -v` from PowerShell?

Comment: Both `cmd` and `cmd /c node -v` run in and output to the same console window. IOW, they don't spawn a new console.

Comment: What happens if you do `node -v | echo` in PowerShell? Show output of `$env:Path` and `$env:PathExt`.

Comment: `node -v | echo` pops up a new console. No output in PS windows. `$env:PathExt`: `.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.CPL`. Path is too long to paste in comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141489/discussion-between-petseral-and-ron-ratzlaff).